# Save and print list with array

Tags: javascript

I need help print and save element in an array in javascript. I know that I have to create an array, and then use a for-loop to save and print it, but i don't know how. What i want to do i so make a simple currency converter, use a for-loop with an array to save the converted input and display it. Here is my code:

JAVASCRIPT

```
var input = document.querySelector("#input");
var convert = document.querySelector("#convert");

var dollar = 0.51;
var euro = 0.11;

omvandla.onclick = function (){
    if(isNaN(input.value)){
        alert ("Use numbers");
    }
    else{
        console.log(("Dollar:" + input.value*dollar) + ("Euro:" + input.value*euro));
    }
};
```

HTML

```
<p>
    <form>
            <label>Kronor: <input type="text" id="kronor"/></label>
            <br><input type="submit" id="convert" value="Omvandla"/>
   </from>
</p>
```

How can I append the converted value after the submit button?

Comment: this seems valid code, so what is the problem?

Comment: You can access an element of an array by using the `array[i]` syntax, where i is the number of the element you want to access. [You can read more about arrays here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display one Conversion Result after another, you could do this like this:

```
var input = document.querySelector("#kronor");
var convert = document.querySelector("#convert");

var dollar = 0.51;
var euro = 0.11;
var conversionArray = [];

convert.onclick = function (){
    if(isNaN(input.value)){
        alert ("Use numbers");
    }
    else{
        var dollarResult = input.value*dollar;
        var euroResult = input.value*euro;

        var newArrayEl = {
            dollar: dollarResult, 
            euro: euroResult
        };

        conversionArray.push(newArrayEl);
        console.log(conversionArray);

        document.getElementById("convertedValue").innerHTML = "Dollar: " + dollarResult + " Euro: " + euroResult + "<br>" + document.getElementById("convertedValue").innerHTML;

    }
};
```

Then you can access single values of the conversion by e.g. `conversionArray[indexOfElement].dollar`

This way you don't need an array to store the values. If you really need thos wvalues again, let me know, and im showing you how to store the array.

[Here is a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gLLXu/31/), that shows how it works.

Comment: That is what i want, but you are welcome to show me how to store the array, since i don't know how to to that. :)

Comment: I updated the code and the fiddle ;) look in the console, there you can see your array grow

Comment: Where did you make the changes? I can't see it :s

Comment: When i test it in the fiddle, the console says: Uncaught ReferenceError: input is not defined

Comment: Ofc!! :) But the last thing i want to ask is, how do i get the numbers to get to two decimals ^^

Comment: Just use `YourValueVariable.toFixed(2)`

Comment: I notice now that the input takes empty strings. How can i solve that?

Answer (score 0):

In javascript the way you add elements to an array is the push function

```
var myArray = [];
myArray.push(15);
```

Then to loop through the elements you can do something like this

```
for(var elem in myArray){
   //Do something with elem
}
```

From your problem description it is hard to figure out what you are trying to do with your code. Hopefully this will help with array manipulation

Comment: Im trying to do a currency converter, where the array should print out the the converted input, and print it out as a list one element after the other.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an element to the end of an array by using the `array.push()` function. I your example you would do something like:

```
array = [];
...
omvandla.onclick = function (){
    if(isNaN(input.value)){
        alert ("Use numbers");
    }
    else{
        console.log(...);
        array.push(input.value);
    }
};
```

[For more information about JavaScript arrays see here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: Ok, how can i write so that i add the value that comes from "input.value*euro" and print it in the webbside?

Comment: @user3116639 To add the value of `input.value * euro` all you would need to do is pass it to the `array.push()` function like: `array.push(input.value * euro)`

Comment: But still it isn't shown.. My html-code looks like this: <form>
            <label>Kronor: <input type="text" id="input"/></label>
            <br><input type="submit" id="convert" value="Convert"/>
    </from>

Comment: @user3116639 You don't seem to understand JavaScript Arrays. JavaScript arrays are simply a data structure for JavaScript. They do not display themselves in html. What exactly is "it", what is not being shown.

Comment: Ok. What can i use to display the elements in the array?

Comment: You can log the array to the console by using `console.log()` or you can skip the whole array business and simply append an element to the DOM to display the results. You can also use a **M** odel **V** iew **C** ontroller framework too.