# Hide and show table

Tags: javascript

I need help with hiding and show a table in Javascript. My javascript is very short and that is because I want to use setAttribute and getAttribut I some way to hide and show the table when clicking on the link "Hide/show".

HTML

```
<a href="#" id="link">Hide/show</a></p>
        <table class="show" class="hide">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>First</th>
                    <th>Second</th>
                    <th>Third</th>
               </tr>
           </thead>
        </table>
```

CSS

```
 .hide{
    display:none;
 }

 .show{
    display:block;
 }
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
     var linkhideShow = document.querySelector("#hideshow");
     var show = document.querySelector(".show");
     var hide = document.querySelector(".hide");

      link.onclick = function() {
      if (){

      }
        else{

      }

    };
```

Regards!

Comment: What have you tried in the javascript part? Also, why are you using 2 class attributes?

Comment: What is `link`? Have you got some other JS that actually declares and sets `link` to the element in question yet, or...?

Comment: This should be in the javascript also:                               var linkhideShow = document.querySelector("#hideshow");
var show = document.querySelector(".show");
var hide = document.querySelector(".hide");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your table a id like this, and use only one class attribute:

```
<table class="table" id="table1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>First</th>
                    <th>Second</th>
                    <th>Third</th>
               </tr>
           </thead>
        </table>
```

Then set your default value in the css class table or however you want to call it to `display:hidden;` or `display:none'`

And then check if your element is shown or hidden and edit the attribute like this:

```
 var table = document.getElementById("table1");
 document.getElementById('link').onclick = function() {
        if(table.styl.display == "none"){
            table.style.display = "block";
        }else{
            table.style.display = "none";
        }};
```

Here is a [working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FW66w/8/)

Comment: I not familiar to window.getComputedStyle or  getPropertyValue, what do they do?

Comment: `getComputedStyle()` gives the values of all the CSS properties of an element after applying the active stylesheets and resolving any basic computation those values may contain. And `getPropertyValue("propertyName")` then gives you the value of a specific property.

Comment: can i in some way use setAttribute and getAttribut instead of getComputedStyle() and the getPropertyValue("propertyName")?

Comment: I wouldnt recommend so, because this works inconsistently, and totally fails in ie...If you don't wan't to use the computedStyle, you could also go by `table.style.display == "none"`in the if statement. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/FW66w/8/

Comment: Ok, i understand! But could you show i it should look anyway?

Comment: I edited the code in the answer. This is how it works with Element.style

Comment: Maybe you could help me with another problem i asked for help with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20667078/save-and-print-list-with-array. That would be more than awesome.

Comment: I can but first you have to clarify what you are exactly asking there, so that it will be reopened

Comment: Ok, i don't think i understand what you want me to do... :S

Answer (score 0):

Try this way :

```
<a href="#" id="link">Hide/show</a></p>
 <table id="table "class="show">
     <thead>
         <tr>
             <th>First</th>
             <th>Second</th>
             <th>Third</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
  </table>
  <script>
    document.getElementById('link').onclick = function() {
        var t = document.getElementById('table');
        if(t.classList.contains("show")){
            t.className='hide';
        }else{
            t.className='show';
        }};
  </script>
```

Comment: Do you mean that i should write the last part i html or in javascript? I want to have a code looking like this but written in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

To get you started ([fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/kFaCA/)):

```
<a href="#" id="link" onclick="
 var elm = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
 elm.style.display = elm.style.display ? '' : 'none';
">Hide/show</a>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First</th>
            <th>Second</th>
            <th>Third</th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
</table>
```

**Edit** (after your updated question):

```
link.onclick = function(){
    var elm = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
    elm.style.display = elm.style.display ? '' : 'none';
}
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kFaCA/1/) here.

Short explanation:
the ternary statement (elm.style.display = elm.style.display ? '' : 'none';) is like an if else:

```
variable = condition   ? /*true*/    :   /*false*/ ;
if(condition){variable = /*true*/;} else {variable = /*false*/;};
```

Normally elements have their `style.display` unset, so it is an empty string. Empty strings evaluate to false in javascript. So, when the style.display is 'none', then the string is not empty. Thus, when style.display is set (to `none`), then set it to `''` otherwise set it to `'none'`.

Another important note: when an element's `style.display` is unset, the browser will render the element in the element's default display mode. Inline elements (like span) will be `inline`, block elements (like div) will have `block` and table elements will have `table` (*not block*).
So, setting the elements style.display to '' (instead of 'block') we assure the element get's it's default display mode (also it solves some weird cross browser issues).

Naturally you could also make a toggle function this way (passing the element to toggle as an argument):

```
function toggle(elm){
    elm.style.display = elm.style.display ? '' : 'none';
}
// example use: toggle( document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0] );
```

NOTE:
Your table should NOT have two class attributes like this: `class="show" class="hide"`.

Also note: In HTML an element's class attribute can have multiple classes separated by spaces: `<elm class="class_a class_b"></elm>`. In order to reliably *add/delete* a class one would require another (somewhat heavy) function (because if you would set the full class-attribute, you'd *overwrite* it completely).

It would be better to give the table an unique `ID` and reference it via this `ID`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: But i want to have write it in javascript. seperate javascript with html. In some way write the "onclick="
 var elm=document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
 elm.style.display=elm.style.display ? '': 'none';" in javascript.

Comment: The code you wrote i don't understand, the one i'm familiar with is the one that "Kamlesh" wrote, but that code i can't get working, and i would like to use the onclick in javascript, like this: link.onlick = function ();

Comment: what part don't you understand? is it the ternary statement : `elm.style.display = elm.style.display ? '' : 'none';`

Comment: Yes! and toggle function. Because i understand "Kamlesh" code i would like to use something like that, don't want to write something i can't understand.

Comment: updated my answer. Also note: In HTML an element's class attribute can have multiple classes separated by spaces: `<elm class="class_a class_b"></elm>`. In order to reliably add/delete a class one would require another (somewhat heavy) function (because if you would set the full class-attribute, you'd overwrite it completely).

Comment: And I've added another important note.

Answer (score 0):

using jquery you can simple do it as follows

```
$('#linkId').click(function () {
                $('#tabelId').toggle();
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Chagne HTML as show below

```
<a href='#' id='link' onclick="ToogleClass();">Show/Hide</a>
<table id="table" class="show">
 <thead>
     <tr>
         <th>First</th>
         <th>Second</th>
         <th>Third</th>
     </tr>
  </thead>
```

In Script tag put following

```
function ToogleClass() {
var tableS = document.getElementById("table");
if ( tables.getAttribute("class") == "hide"){
tables.setAttribute("class","show");
} 
else {
tables.setAttribute("class","hide");
}

}
```

Comment: should i have the display:block in the css?

Comment: you can add display:block in css or try display:'' if block not working

Comment: You should not use getAttribute and setAttribute, because this works inconsistently. In IE it's kinda broken...